# replace a capture group followed by a number

Tags: regex, visual-studio

In visual studio's find and replace, I'm trying to replace (P|Q)1 with the p or the Q followed by a 2. So P1 with P2 and Q1 with Q2. however, `$12` seems to look for capture group 12 so it just shows up as literally `$12`. Any character I put between the 1 and the 2, including backslash, shows up. Can this be done?

Comment: Use `${1}2`, should work on VS2013+

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thanks, that's the answer

Comment: But your regex is better written as `\b([PQ])1\b` (if these are whole words) or just `([PQ])1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely use

```
([PQ])1
```

and replace with `${1}2` (since `{}` around the group ID makes the ID unambiguous) even in **VS2012**.

If you are unsure of what is going on with numbered backreferences, you can always use named captures:

```
(?<val>[PQ])1
```

and replace with `${val}2`.

[image]